# Parsing python with PLY, how to code the indent and dedent part

Tags: python, grammar, indentation, ply

I was trying to parse the function definition for the python language with PLY.
I am encountering issues related to the indentation.
For instance for a for statement, I would like to be able to know when the block ends.
I read the python grammar here: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html
And the grammar for this part is:

```
for_stmt: 'for' exprlist 'in' testlist ':' suite ['else' ':' suite]
suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT
```

I don't know how to describe the INDENT and DEDENT tokens with PLY.
I was trying something like:

```
def t_indentation(t):
    r'    |\t'
    #some special treatment for the indentation.
```

But it seems that PLY consider that regexes with spaces match the empty string and does not build the lexer...
Even if I would have managed to have the INDENT token I am not sure about the way to get the DEDENT one...

Is there a way to do that with PLY?

Comment: The rules about INDENT and DEDENT in Python are more complex than four spaces or a tab. In other parser generators the problem is solved using semantic actions that determine if the amount of leading space is a valid indent or dedent, or by intervening the tokenizer to inject INDENT or DEDENT tokens.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about doing the token injection with the t_indentation function. The regex was wrong for PLY, r'[ ]{4}|\t' is better. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that with plyplus, there is an easier way to do so: https://github.com/erezsh/plyplus/blob/master/plyplus/grammars/python_indent_postlex.py

Answer (score 3):

You have to use states to parse INDENT and UNDENT.

[example](https://github.com/woshifyz/zlang/blob/master/zlexer.py) of parsing python like language

Comment: That example does not use states to parse INDENT and UNDENT; it uses a postprocessing step.

Answer (score 3):

PLY includes in its examples one for a subset of Python to demonstrate how to handle indentation:

https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/tree/1321375e013425958ea090b55aecae0a4b7face6/example/GardenSnake

Comment: links dead now, since it was removed in the most recent version of PLY, but the old version is here: https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/blob/3.11/example/GardenSnake/GardenSnake.py